# É possível reduzir esta expressão condicional?

Tags: javascript

No meu projeto eu me deparo constantemente com este tipo de expressão condicional:

```
if(cliente && cliente.id) {
    return cliente.id;
} else {
    return '';
}
```

Ou seja, *"caso haja um cliente e este cliente tenha um id então retorne o valor do id, caso contrário retorne uma string vazia"*. Esta expressão é útil por duas razões;

1- Evitar exceções do tipo `Cannot read property of undefined/null`
 2- Não retornar o literal `undefined` para a interface

Existe alguma maneira de reduzir esta expressão?

**Observação:** O valor zero não faz parte do conjunto de *ids* possíveis.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Sim**,

Para reduzir esta expressão devemos levar em conta que o JavaScript avalia uma expressão condicional retornando o último valor da expressão, que por sua vez é avaliado como *falsy [1]* ou não.

#### Exemplo

```
console.log(true && 200 && 'foobar');  //foobar
console.log(true && 200 && true);      //true
console.log(false && 200 && 'foobar'); //false
console.log(0 && 200 && 'foobar');     //0
```

*Contra intuitivamente alguém vindo de outras linguagens poderia supor que os resultados possíveis seriam apenas `true` ou `false`*.

#### Conclusão

Para reduzirmos a expressão apresentada podemos utilizar o [operador lógico *or*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Logical_operators) juntamente com o conceito apresentado acima, resultando no seguinte código *one-liner*.

```
return cliente && cliente.id || '';
```

*"Caso haja um cliente e este cliente tenha um id então retorne o valor do id, caso contrário retorne uma string vazia"*

---

**[1]** Um valor que não é falso de fato, mas de acordo com a especificação se comporta como se fosse. Veja: http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/

Comment: Excelente resposta, +1! Gosto de ver respostas detalhadas e explicativas como esta; já aprendi mais uma coisinha de JavaScript hoje, então! o/